# New angular project how to set home page

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am new to angular

I have created the new project by using this link `https://cli.angular.io/`

Here the home page is displayed from `appcomponent.html`

I have created the new page in SRC >> pages >> index.html and index.ts

I import these pages in `appcomponent.ts` and `appmodule.ts`

How to set the default home page as index.

this is my app component page

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { IndexPage } from '../pages/index';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class MyApp {
  title = 'app';
  rootPage:any = IndexPage;


  constructor(    public http: Http ) {

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 10):

You have to generate a new Component with ng g c MyComponent. Then add 
`<router-outlet></router-outlet>` 
to your app.component.html file. Finally you have to configure your Router to display this component at your main address (at localhost:4200). Object should look like

```
const routesConfig: Routes = [
    { path: '',     component: MyComponent}
    ]
```

Read more about Router and Routing https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: Why is Angular so cryptic?

Answer (score 2):

in app-rounting.module.ts

```
{path: "",  component: DashboardComponent, pathMatch: "full"},
```